# Angular 2 ngSwitch nested in ngFor

Tags: angular

What is the correct way to use an `ngSwitch` within an `ngFor`?

If I do the following I receive the error

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

```html
<span *ngFor="let action of actions">
    <span [ngSwitch]="{{action}}">
        <span *ngSwitchCase='edit'>Edit</span>
        <span *ngSwitchCase='delete'>Delete</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bindings with `(...)` or `[...]` you don't need to interpolate your variable to a string, you can just use it as is to bind it.

```html
<span [ngSwitch]="action">
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually tried that, but it didn't appear to work given I didn't enclose the `ngSwitchCase` strings in double quotes.

Comment: Now that you say it - you're right. Since `ngSwitchCase` expects an expression, you have to pass either a variable or a string enclosed by quotes.

Comment: Just for clarification for other people visiting here, Steve's "double quotes" means double sets of quotes, ```" ' ' "```, and not just ```" "```

Answer (score 3):

```
<span *ngFor="let action of actions">
    <span [ngSwitch]="{{action}}">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'edit'">Edit</span>
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'delete'">Delete</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

For `*ngSwitchCase` if the value is a string we need to pass it within double quotes and then with single quotes like above mentioned: `*ngSwitchCase="'delete'"`

Comment: However [ngSwitch]="{{action}}" will work as [ngSwitch]="action"

Comment: Curly braces inside an input binding are not correct